# How to get the tag name using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

If you have an XElement obj how do you get the tag name of the xelement object?

```
doc.Descendants("name").Where(x => (string) x == cit.name).FirstOrDefault().Parent
```

i would like to get the tagname of this xelement object.

Comment: I am confused... the `XElement.Name` is not good?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have the right `XElement`, you can use [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx) property like so:

```
<someNamespace:someElement attr="blah"/>
```

```
string name = element.Name.LocalName;
//will get "someElement"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Descendants("name").Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("") == cit.name).FirstOrDefault().Parent
```